# Kendo UI with AngularJs: How to bind data on textbox fields when user select row in a grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I am working with Kendo UI and angular grid application. In my application I define Kendo TabStrip. In first tab I have Kendo UI grid with data and second tab contains appropriate textbox fields, which are to be filled when user select some row in a grid. My grid is populated with data when load page and it work perfectly, but data binding to textbox fields not working. How to bind data on textbox fields when user select row in a grid?

This is my JSON data (which is in separate file):

```
[
  { "Id": 1, "AccountNo": "10236", "PostingDate": "20.01.2015", "MaturityDate": "24.01.2015", "Description": "description1", "DocumentType": "doc1" },
  { "Id": 2, "AccountNo": "10648", "PostingDate": "26.01.2015", "MaturityDate": "28.01.2015", "Description": "description2", "DocumentType": "doc2" },
  { "Id": 3, "AccountNo": "10700", "PostingDate": "22.01.2015", "MaturityDate": "25.01.2015", "Description": "description3", "DocumentType": "doc3" },
  { "Id": 4, "AccountNo": "10810", "PostingDate": "24.01.2015", "MaturityDate": "27.01.2015", "Description": "description4", "DocumentType": "doc4" },
  { "Id": 5, "AccountNo": "10101", "PostingDate": "29.01.2015", "MaturityDate": "30.01.2015", "Description": "description5", "DocumentType": "doc5" },
  { "Id": 6, "AccountNo": "10364", "PostingDate": "25.01.2015", "MaturityDate": "31.01.2015", "Description": "description6", "DocumentType": "doc6" }


]
```

This is my angular service (which is in separate file):

```
angular.module("app").factory('myService', function ($http) {

  return {
      getAll: function (onSuccess, onError) {
          return $http.get('/Scripts/app/data/json/master/masterGridData.js').success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              onSuccess(data);
          }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              onError(data);
          });
      }
  }


});
```

This is my controller (which is in separate file):

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["kendo.directives"]).controller("myController", function ($scope, myService) {

$scope.tabStrip = null;
$scope.$watch('tabStrip', function () {
    $scope.tabStrip.select(0);
});

$scope.masterDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            url = "/Scripts/app/data/json/master/masterGridData.js",
            myService.getAll(function (data) {
                options.success(data);
            }).error(function (data) {
                options.error(data);
            })
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { type: "number" },
                AccountNo: { type: "string" },
                PostingDate: { type: "string" },
                MaturityDate: { type: "string" },
                Description: { type: "string" },
                DocumentType: { type: "string" }
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 16
});

$scope.gridMaster = {
    columns: [
            { field: "Id", hidden: true },
            { field: "AccountNo", title: "Account No", width: "77px", template: '<div style="text-align:left;">#= kendo.toString(AccountNo) #</div>' },
            { field: "PostingDate", title: "Posting Date", width: "70px" },
            { field: "MaturityDate", title: "Maturity Date" width: "70px" },
            { field: "Description", title: "Description", width: "170px" },
            { field: "DocumentType", hidden: true }
    ],
    dataSource: $scope.masterDataSource,
    selectable: true,
    filterable: true,
    scrollable: true,
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 16,
        //refresh: true,
        pageSizes: ["50", "100", "200", "All"]
    },
    toolbar: [{
        name: "create"
    }]
};


});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- css and javaScript files -->
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">
     <div class="divH3Style">
         <h3 class="h3LabelForm">Grid Master</h3>
     </div>
     <div id="tabstrip" class="k-tabstrip-wrapper" data-kendo-tab-strip="tabStrip">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Overview</li>
                                <li>Update</li>
                            </ul>


                        <div id="tabstrip-1">
                            <div id="gridMaster" kendo-grid k-options="gridMaster" k-data-source="masterDataSource">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="tabstrip-2" style="overflow: hidden">
                            <div id="tabStrip2Half1">
                                <div class="divHeightStyle">
                                    <label for="accountNumber" class="labelTextSize">Account Number:</label>
                                    <input id="accountNumber" type="number" class="k-textboxField" name="accountNumber" ng-model="masterDataSource.data.AccountNo" placeholder="Account Number" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="datepickerStyle">
                                    <label for="postingDate" class="labelTextSize">Posting Date:</label>
                                    <input id="postingDate" class="k-datetimepickerMaster" name="postingDate" ng-model="masterDataSource.data.PostingDate" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="divHeightStyle">
                                    <label for="desccription" class="labelTextSize">Description:</label>
                                    <input id="desccription" type="text" class="k-textboxField" name="description" placeholder="Description" ng-model="masterDataSource.data.Description" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="datepickerStyle">
                                    <label for="maturityDate" class="labelTextSize">Maturity Date:</label>
                                    <input id="maturityDate" class="k-datetimepickerMaster" name="maturityDate" ng-model="masterDataSource.data.MaturityDate" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="tabStrip2Half2">
                                <div class="divHeightStyle">
                                    <label for="documentType" class="labelTextSize">Document Type:</label>
                                    <input id="documentType" type="text" class="k-textboxField" name="documentType" placeholder="Document Type" ng-model="masterDataSource.data.DocumentType" />
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <button type="button" id="saveDataMasterGrid" class="k-button buttonSaveCancel" onclick="saveDataMasterGrid()">Save</button>
                                    <button type="button" id="cancelDataMasterGrid" class="k-button buttonSaveCancel" onclick="cancelButtonMasterGrid()">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am solve that problem. I was added change event function in $scope.gridMaster:

```
$scope.gridMaster = {
    ...
    change: function () {
        var dataItem = this.dataItem(this.select());
        $scope.accountNumber = dataItem.AccountNo;
        $scope.postingDate = dataItem.PostingDate;
        $scope.description = dataItem.Description;
        $scope.maturityDate = dataItem.MaturityDate;
        $scope.documentType = dataItem.DocumentType;
    }
}
```

And I was change ng-model in my HTML page:

```
<div id="tabstrip-2" style="overflow: hidden">
                        <div id="tabStrip2Half1">
                            <div class="divHeightStyle">
                                <label for="accountNumber" class="labelTextSize">Account Number:</label>
                                <input id="accountNumber" type="number" class="k-textboxField" name="accountNumber" ng-model="accountNumber" placeholder="Account Number" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="datepickerStyle">
                                <label for="postingDate" class="labelTextSize">Posting Date:</label>
                                <input id="postingDate" class="k-datetimepickerMaster" name="postingDate" ng-model="postingDate" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="divHeightStyle">
                                <label for="desccription" class="labelTextSize">Description:</label>
                                <input id="desccription" type="text" class="k-textboxField" name="description" placeholder="Description" ng-model="description" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="datepickerStyle">
                                <label for="maturityDate" class="labelTextSize">Maturity Date:</label>
                                <input id="maturityDate" class="k-datetimepickerMaster" name="maturityDate" ng-model="maturityDate" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="tabStrip2Half2">
                            <div class="divHeightStyle">
                                <label for="documentType" class="labelTextSize">Document Type:</label>
                                <input id="documentType" type="text" class="k-textboxField" name="documentType" placeholder="Document Type" ng-model="documentType" />
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <button type="button" id="saveDataMasterGrid" class="k-button buttonSaveCancel" onclick="saveDataMasterGrid()">Save</button>
                                <button type="button" id="cancelDataMasterGrid" class="k-button buttonSaveCancel" onclick="cancelButtonMasterGrid()">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```