# How can use mutual exclusion for two textbox fields

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on [grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567007/kendo-ui-with-angularjs-how-to-bind-data-on-textbox-fields-when-user-select-row/) and I have two textboxes in html and i use angularjs. How can use mutual exclusion for my textboxes. If I input some value in first textbox, second textbox must be disabled. If I input some value in second textbox, first textbox must be disabled. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working code...

```
<div ng-app>
        <input type="text" ng-model="test" ng-disabled="test1">
        <input type="text" ng-model="test1" ng-disabled="test">
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/p1hshwan/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with [`ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and [`ngDisabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled).

```
<input ng-model="vm.input1" ng-disabled="vm.input2">
<input ng-model="vm.input2" ng-disabled="vm.input1">
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2622/)**</kbd>